# Why is this JavaScript timer crashing my web page?

Tags: javascript, timer, countdown

So I'm trying to put together a timer to count down to a specific time on a specific day. I found some code to work with online and adapted it to this

```
var Timer;
var TotalSeconds;

function CreateTimer(TimerID, Time)
{
    Timer = document.getElementByID(TimerID);
    TotalSeconds = Time;
    UpdateTimer()
    window.setTimeout("Tick()", 1000);
}
window.setTimeout("Tick()", 1000);
function Tick()
{
    if (TotalSeconds <= 0)
    {
        alert("Time's up!")
        return;
    }

    TotalSeconds -= 1;
    UpdateTimer()
    window.setTimeout("Tick()", 1000);
}

function UpdateTimer()
{
    var Seconds = TotalSeconds;
    var Days = Math.floor(Seconds / 86400);
    Seconds -= Days * 86400;

    var Hours = Math.floor(Seconds / 3600);
    Seconds -= Hours * (3600);

    var Minutes = Math.floor(Seconds / 60);
    Seconds -= Minutes * (60);


    var TimeStr = ((Days > 0) ? Days + " days " : "") + LeadingZero(Hours) + ":" + LeadingZero(Minutes) + ":" + LeadingZero(Seconds)


    Timer.innerHTML = TimeStr + " until my birthday!";
}


function LeadingZero(Time)
{
    return (Time < 10) ? "0" + Time : + Time;
}
```

When I start it up on my web page it crashes the page. I know the problem is not how I link it to the HTML because I tested this code on http://writecodeonline.com/javascript/ and it did not work there either. Any advice?

Comment: When do you call `CreateTimer`? Can you make a jsfiddle that shows how you're using it?

Comment: I'm calling it in an HTML page. <script type="text/javascript">window.onload = CreateTimer("timer", 30);</script>

Comment: One problem is that you have two timers running: one created by calling `CreateTimer` from the `onload` handler, the other because you call `window.setTimeout` in the top-level of this script.